# How do i store a tar directory on s3 in node js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream, aws-sdk

Using the AWS SDK, I'm able to store a file (compressed or uncompressed) and a compressed directory (using tar), but not an uncompressed directory.

Setup and dependencies:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk'),
    s3 = new aws.S3(),
    fs = require('fs'),
    fstream = require('fstream'),
    zlib = require('zlib'),
    tar = require('tar'),
    key = 'test',
    bucket = 'mybucket';
```

Trimmed down upload code:

```
var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    Body: body
};
s3.upload(params)
    .send(function(err, data) {
            console.log("data:", data);
        }
    });
```

Store file, uncompressed:

```
body = fs.createReadStream('/var/www/file.txt');
```

Store file, compressed:

```
body = fs.createReadStream('/var/www/file.txt')
    .pipe(zlib.createGzip());
```

Store directory, compressed:

```
body = fstream.Reader({type: "Directory", path: "/var/www"})
    .pipe(tar.Pack())
    .pipe(zlib.Gzip());
```

**Store directory, uncompressed (doesn't work):**

```
body = fstream.Reader({type: "Directory", path: "/var/www"})
    .pipe(tar.Pack());
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/s3/managed_upload.js:346
    var buf = self.body.read(self.partSize - self.partBuffer.length) ||
                        ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at ManagedUpload.fillStream (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/s3/managed_upload.js:346:25)
    at Pack.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/s3/managed_upload.js:167:28)
    at Pack.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at Pack._process (node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js:121:8)
    at Pack.end (node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js:87:8)
    at DirReader.onend (stream.js:79:10)
    at DirReader.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at DirReader._read (node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-reader.js:82:10)
    at FileReader.onend (node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-reader.js:172:12)
    at FileReader.emit (events.js:129:20)
```

Do I need to pipe the tar result into something the aws sdk can handle, or what?